# Substituir palavra de várias divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supondo que eu tenha:

```
<div class='datas'>
 <span>01-01-2019</span>
 <span>01-02-2019</span>
</div>

<div class='datas'>
 <span>01-03-2019</span>
 <span>01-03-2019</span>
</div>
```

Como posso trocar todos os traços por barras de forma que fique no formato dia/mês/ano?

Comment: Uma boa prática seria renderizar a data já formatada, pra todos os cenários possíveis isso seria o melhor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ericki,

Existe várias formas de fazer isso, abaixo dois exemplos, utilizando apenas JS e outra com JQuery:

```js
//Com JS puro
function transformaData() {
  //Pego as divs com a class datas
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("datas");

  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    //Para cada div, procura as tags span
    let spans = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("span");

    for (let j = 0; j < spans.length; j++) {
      //Altera o valor presente, substituindo o (-) por (/)
      spans[j].innerHTML = spans[j].innerHTML.replace(/-/g, "/");
    }
  }
}

//JQuery
$(function(){
    //Adiciona via JQuery o click no botão
    $("#btn-jquery").click( function() {
      //Procura a tag span dentro da class datas
      $(".datas span").each( function() {
        //O each vai entrar nessa função para cada elemento encontrado
        let value = $(this).text();
        //Pego o valor anterior, altero e já faço a atualização do mesmo no elemento
        $(this).text( value.replace(/-/g, "/") );
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='datas'>
  <span>01-01-2019</span>
  <span>01-02-2019</span>
</div>

<div class='datas'>
  <span>01-03-2019</span>
  <span>01-04-2019</span>
</div>

<button onclick="transformaData()">Alterar data apenas com JS</button>
<button id="btn-jquery">Alterar data com JQuery</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solução:

1. Faça um foreach de cada elemento com método `each`.
2. Save em um let os valores que foi retornado do método `replace`
3. Coloque o valor dentro no HTML com o método `text`.

```js
function substituir_palavara_de_varias_divs() {
  $(".datas span").each(function(index) {
    let replace = $(this).text().replace(/-/g, "/");
    $(this).text(replace);
  });
}
substituir_palavara_de_varias_divs()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='datas'>
  <span>01-01-2019</span>
  <span>01-02-2019</span>
</div>

<div class='datas'>
  <span>01-03-2019</span>
  <span>01-04-2019</span>
</div>
```

Fonte:

[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

[String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)